# My data-backdrop does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at other options with the data-backdrop to prevent the model from closing when clicking outside of the close button. Perhaps it could be that I add the backdrop to the wrong piece of code but I was hoping you could help me on this.

```js
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1670;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: scroll;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* home page special button Content */

.special-content {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #755378;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="Star-btn" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="onClick(this)">Specials</a>

<div id="modal01" class="modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="special-content">
    <p id="img01" class="TextHome" alt="">random inforomation.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

It is probably an easy fix or something small that needs to be added but I can't seem to manage, I would appreciate any help

Regards 
Francois

Comment: Simple remove the onclick handler from `#model01` and put it into `.close`. Then call a seperate close function or go to `parentElement` and hide it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Star-btn").click(function(){
        $("#modal01").css({"display":"block"});
    });
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#modal01").css({"display":"none"});
    });

});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1670;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: scroll;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* home page special button Content */

.special-content {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
}
/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #755378;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="Star-btn" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Specials</a>

<div id="modal01" class="modal">

  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="special-content">
    <p id="img01" class="TextHome" alt="">random inforomation.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```